# How to change the column names of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with n columns , don't know how many columns will be there.

```
    df = index  task_1   task_2 ......
          0     dummy_1   dummy_2 ....
          1     dum_1     dum_2 ...
```

I want to change the names of the column from task_1 to Label_1 and so on.The out put needs to be

```
    df = index  Label_1   Label_2 ......
          0     dummy_1   dummy_2 ....
          1     dum_1     dum_2 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to find out how many columns are there

You can do that by

`len(df.columns)`

and you can change the names in sequence by iterating through a loop for eg"

```
df.columns=["Label_"+str(i) for i in range(1, 17)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all columns and replace `"task"` with `"Label"` like this. And this only applies to columns that has `"task"` in their name and others remains unchanged:

```py
df.columns = [name.replace('task', 'Label') for name in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method, passing a dictionary to the `columns` argument where the keys are the old column names and the values are the new column names:

```py
df.rename(columns={"task_1": "Label_1"}, inplace=True)
```